# How to add fonts in cygwin mintty

Tags: fonts, terminal, cygwin, mintty

**I wish to use additional fonts in [image]mintty,**
I want to add Monaco font to my cygwin terminal. While mintty does help me to customise fonts and appearance. I cannot get to use additional fonts.
I added Monaco from internet to my Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Fonts folder and it's usable in wordpad and word but not in mintty.

Answer (score 7):

This is easy, but you cannot use the mintty UI to change it.  Instead, create a file `/etc/minttyrc` or edit the file `~/.minttyrc`.

Set the font (and other settings) there.  Check the [man page](https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html) for complete list of settings.

```
Font=Monaco
FontHeight=12
```

You can find the available font names in the standard Windows font dialog in the config panel.